# Couldn't match expected type `m0 ...'

Tags: haskell

Dealing with following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `m0 KAutomat'
            with actual type `KAutomat'
In the second argument of `firstFor', namely `ts'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  tsko <- firstFor (take 1 $ Set.toList $ setW ts) ts
In the expression:
  do { tsko <- firstFor (take 1 $ Set.toList $ setW ts) ts;
       reduce tsko }
```

Here is snippet of my code:

```
reduce ts 
| (Set.null (setW ts))==False = do
    tsko <- firstFor (take 1 $ Set.toList $ setW ts) ts
    reduce tsko
| otherwise = return ts

firstFor x ts = ts
```

`ts` is of type KAutomat. I believe you don't bigger amount of code. If you do, just tell me.

I've read something about `m0` stuff and I already know it has something to do with Monads. Though don't know how to fix this. Could you help me?

What I actually try to do is to simulate `while` cycle with the condition at the begin. I test if the set `(setW ts)` is empty, if it is not, I take the first item from it and pass it altogether with ts to function `firstFor`. And again - until set `(setW ts)` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to your own code

```
reduce ts 
| (Set.null (setW ts))==False = do
    tsko <- firstFor (take 1 $ Set.toList $ setW ts) ts
    ...    
firstFor x ts = ts
```

we see that `firstFor` is simply returning the second argument, so the above actually means

```
reduce ts 
| (Set.null (setW ts))==False = do
    tsko <- ts
    ...
```

To extract `tsko` from the monadic value `ts`, we need `ts` to have a monadic type, and `KAutomat` is not monadic.

What are you trying to achieve? What is the intended type of `reduce`?

You might need `let tsko = ts` instead, or maybe you need to remove all your `do`s since you are not dealing with any monad, and replacing them with `let ... in ...` or something similar.

It is very hard to tell from your question. I'd recommend you do not write any code for a function until you have written an explicit type signature for it, e.g.

```
reduce :: KAutomat -> ....

firstFor :: ... -> ... -> ...
```

Doing this would usually help GHC to produce better type error messages.

Comment: I plan to work with the value of the `ts` variable in function `firstFor` and then return it and save it into `tsko`. Thats why I can't use `let` in the way you suggest.

Comment: Well, what I actually try to do is to simulate `while` cycle with the condition at the begin. I test if the set (setW ts) is empty, if it is not, I take the first item from it and pass it altogether with `ts` to function 'firstFor'. And again, again..until set (setW ts) is empty.